# Do I need to integrate InMobi sdk if I am already using admob

Tags: android, admob, inmobi

I have been using AdMob as a sole ad network for my app for a while. But the fill rate has dropped significantly recently, so I started seeing other options and I stumbled upon InMobi. So I created an account obtained the necessary IDs(placement and account). and I added these information to the AdMob mediation settings and set it's priority as 1. and waited for a day but still no impressions even though I am getting tons of requests(2.8k to be exact).

Do I need to integrate the sdk into my app source code? If not what could be the issue?

Comment: yes you can implement

Comment: @AD10 without integrating the sdk to my code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to integrate the InMobi SDK in every scenario.

If want to mediate InMobi from AdMob you need to follow [this](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation/inmobi) guideline from the InMobi SDK integration step [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation/inmobi#step_3_import_the_inmobi_sdk_and_adapter).

If you want to completely switch to InMobi as your primary ad provider this is the [guide](https://support.inmobi.com/monetize/android-guidelines/).